# nativescript data has to be displayed grid view with 4*4

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

For displaying the grid view (4*4) in nativescript with Angular, I have integrated the npm "nativescript-grid-view" as per the example in npm site. But, It fails for me. I got the error whenever I enter that page in the application.

Error :

```
System.err: Error: Expecting a valid View instance.
```

System.err: File: "file:///data/data/com.domain.project/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.js, line: 337, column: 12

Code .ts file

```
<GridLayout class="page">
            <GridView [items]="order" colWidth="30%" rowHeight="100">
              <ng-template let-item="item" let-odd="odd">
                <StackLayout margin="10" [nsRouterLink]="['/item', item.id]" borderColor="blue" borderWidth="2" borderRadius="5" verticalAlignment="stretch" class="list-group-item" [class.odd]="odd">
                  <Label verticalAlignment="center" [text]="item.productName" class="list-group-item-text" textWrap="true"></Label>
                </StackLayout>
              </ng-template>
            </GridView>
          </GridLayout>
```

module.ts

```
    import { GridViewModule } from 'nativescript-grid-view/angular';
imports: [
        NativeScriptModule,
        NativeScriptHttpModule,
        NativeScriptUIDataFormModule,
        NativeScriptUIListViewModule,
        GridViewModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
                deps: [Http]
            }
        }),
        ...SHARED_MODULES
    ],....
```

Package.json

```
 "tns-android": {
      "version": "3.0.1"
    },
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "3.4.1"
    }
.....
 "typescript": "~2.2.0",....
```

Somebody has asked the question is below forum, but no one has replied.

https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/dynamic-gridlayout-from-array-angular/1675

Comment: youre using a grid view but arent using the one in nativescript? why?

Comment: I want to dispaly the gridview N * N basis. I have found this npm to display.

Comment: but the gridview is a built in part of nativescript, it does not require any plugins

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use [nativescript-ui-listview](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/Angular/ListView/getting-started) and its `ListViewGridLayout` with `spanCount` property. The official documentation for this functionality is [here](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/Angular/ListView/item-layouts). Basically, you could do the following:

```
<RadListView [items]="dataItems">
    <ng-template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item">
        <!-- item template here -->
    </ng-template>

    <ListViewGridLayout tkListViewLayout spanCount="4" scrollDirection="Vertical" ios:itemHeight="200" ></ListViewGridLayout>
</RadListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

NativeScript 4X4 GridLayout

I have written some code in the nativescript playground link.
**

> https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=a8UEDd

**

```
<GridLayout rows="*,*,*,*" columns="*,*,*,*">
        <Label text="1" row="0" col="0" borderColor="black" borderWidth="1"></Label>
        <Label text="2" row="0" col="1"  borderColor="black" borderWidth="1"></Label>
        <Label text="3" row="0" col="2"  borderColor="black" borderWidth="1"></Label>
        <Label text="4" row="0" col="3"  borderColor="black" borderWidth="1"></Label>
        <Label text="5" row="1" col="0"  borderColor="black" borderWidth="1"></Label>
        <Label text="6" row="1" col="1"  borderColor="black" borderWidth="1"></Label>
        <Label text="7" row="1" col="2"  borderColor="black" borderWidth="1"></Label>
        <Label text="8" row="1" col="3"  borderColor="black" borderWidth="1"></Label>
        <Label text="9" row="2" col="0"  borderColor="black" borderWidth="1"></Label>
        <Label text="10" row="2" col="1"  borderColor="black" borderWidth="1"></Label>
        <Label text="11" row="2" col="2"  borderColor="black" borderWidth="1"></Label>
        <Label text="12" row="2" col="3"  borderColor="black" borderWidth="1"></Label>
        <Label text="13" row="3" col="0"  borderColor="black" borderWidth="1"></Label>
        <Label text="14" row="3" col="1"  borderColor="black" borderWidth="1"></Label>
        <Label text="15" row="3" col="2"  borderColor="black" borderWidth="1"></Label>
        <Label text="16" row="3" col="3"  borderColor="black" borderWidth="1"></Label>
</GridLayout>
```

*Preview of the 4x4 GridLayout will be like this*
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Below code does work without using nativeoscript-grid-view. I think that nativescript version is the problem.

```
<ScrollView class="plansScroll" #plansScroll orientation="vertical" horizontalAlignment="center" width="100%">
    <WrapLayout orientation="horizontal" [id]="myIndex" (tap)="onPlanSectionTap($event)" class="plansScrollGrid m-5" #plansScrollGrid>
            <StackLayout *ngFor='let item of order; let myIndex = index' width="25%">
                    <!-- <Image [src]="item.imagePath" width="80"></Image> -->
                    <Image width="80" [src]="'~/assets/img/bratShop-overlay.jpg'"></Image>
                    <Label [text]='item.productName' textWrap="true" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center" #plansScrollGridType></Label>
                    <Label [text]='item.orderNumber' textWrap="true" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center" #plansScrollGridType></Label>
                    <Label [text]='item.orderStatus' textWrap="true" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center" #plansScrollGridType></Label>
                    <Label [text]='item.orderDate' textWrap="true" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center" #plansScrollGridType></Label>
            </StackLayout>
    </WrapLayout>
```